# Laravel delete method gives "Method not allowed" error on yajra datatable

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem with the following Laravel function, the delete option does not work, it gives out a "Method not allowed" error, for some odd reason even if I give it an id to the route, it fails to show the entire page.

This is the view, admin.unsertable. I just want to correct the "delete" error

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="{{ asset('fonts/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link href="{{ asset('fonts/ionicons.min.csss') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link href="{{ asset('dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
         folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <link href="{{ asset('dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="{{ asset('plugins/iCheck/flat/blue.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- Morris chart -->
    <link href="{{ asset('plugins/morris/morris.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <link href="{{ asset('plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- Date Picker -->
    <link href="{{ asset('plugins/datepicker/datepicker3.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- Daterange picker -->
    <link href="{{ asset('plugins/morris/morris.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <link href="{{ asset('plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
    <!-- bootstrap wysihtml5 - text editor -->
     <link href="{{ asset('public/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
     <header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}" class="logo">
          <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
          <span class="logo-mini"><b>A</b>LT</span>
          <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
          <span class="logo-lg"><b>Plu</b>SIS</span>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
          <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <!-- User Account: style can be found in dropdown.less -->
              <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  <span class="hidden-xs">Usuario</span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <!-- User image -->
                  <li class="user-header">

                    <p>

                    </p>
                  </li>
                  <!-- Menu Body -->
                  <li class="user-body">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                      <!--<a href="#">Followers</a>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                     <!-- <a href="#">Sales</a>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                     <!-- <a href="#">Friends</a>-->
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <!-- Menu Footer-->
                  <li class="user-footer">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                      <a href="{{ route('user.profile', auth()->user()->id) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Perfil</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                      <a href="{{ route('user.logout') }}" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Salir</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
              <li>
                <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>

<body>

<div class="panel-body">
<div id="message">

</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="laravel_datatable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Accion</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
</table>

{{ csrf_field() }}

</div>

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- DataTables -->
        <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        <script>
 $(document).ready( function () {

      fetch_data();

      function fetch_data(){
        $.ajax({
        url:"/shoppingcart/public/admin/usertable/fetch_data",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
          var html = '';
          html += '<tr>';
          html += '<td contenteditable id="email"></td>';
          html += '<td contenteditable id="type"></td>';
          html += '<td><button type="button" class="add" id ="add">Add</button></td></tr>'

          for(var count=0; count < data.length; count++){
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td class="column_name" data-column_name="email" id ="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].email+'</td>';
            html += '<td contenteditable class="column_name" data-column_name="type" id ="'+data[count].id+'">'+data[count].type+'</td>';
            html += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-dange delete" id="'+data[count].id+'">Delete</button></td></tr>'
          }
          $('tbody').html(html);
        }
      })
      }

      var _token = $('input[type="_token"]').val();

      $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
         var type = $('#type').text();
         if(type != ''){

            $.ajax({
               url:"{{ route('admin.add_data') }}",
               method:"POST",
               data:{type:type},
               success:function(data)
               {
                 $('#message').html(data);
                 fetch_data();
               }
            });

         }else{
           $('#message').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>Debes editar el campo</div>");
         }

      });

     });

     $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() { //No obtiene la página, da un error 419 al hacer POST por alguna razón
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
       if(confirm("Estas seguro de esto?"))
       {
         $.ajax({
           url:"{{ route('admin.deleteuser') }}",
           method:"POST",
           data:{id:id},
           success:function(data)
           {
            $('#message').html(data);
            fetch_data();
           }
         })
       }
     });
</script>

</body>
```

Its controller is called AdminController, which runs the following method, which communicates with the database and deletes the row. The database is defined, because if it brings me the data with the method of fetch_data

```
public function deleteuser(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->id)->delete();
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Data deleted</div>';
    }
}
```

These are the routes

```
Route::get('/admin/usertable', 'AdminController@listuser')    
->middleware('is_admin')    
->name('admin.usertable');

Route::get('/admin/usertable/fetch_data', 'AdminController@fetch_data')    
->middleware('is_admin')    
->name('admin.usertable');

Route::delete('/admin/usertable/deleteuser/{id}', 'AdminController@deleteuser')    
->middleware('is_admin')    
->name('admin.deleteuser');
```

Comment: Well, the ajax method is seted to POST, but laravel route method is delete. You can to set a parameter named `_method` with value `'delete'`, also the crsf token on the headers and in a parameter named `_token`. In addition the laravel route expects a parameter `{id}` in the uri, and you're not passing it

Comment: Thanks. So, what would be the corrected version of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax method is seted to `POST`, but Laravel route method is `delete`. You can to set a parameter named `_method` with value `'delete'`, also the `crsf token` on the headers and in a parameter named `_token`. In addition the Laravel route expects a parameter `{id}` in the uri, and you're not passing it.

If you have the csrf token i a metatag, like this:

```
<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

you can get it from there

```
var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

But, if you are in blade, you can directly use the `csrf_token()` helper

```
var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
```

Then, assign the token to the ajax headers:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token,
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    }
});
```

Set a parameter named `_method` with value `'delete'` and set a parameter named `_token` with the token value:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(confirm("Estas seguro de esto?"))
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('admin.deleteuser') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                id:id,
                // set a parameter named _method with value 'delete'
                _method: 'delete',
                // set a parameter named _token with the token value
                _token: token
            },
            success:function(data) {
                //...
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Remove the {id} parameter from your laravel route, since you are not using it:

```
Route::delete('/admin/usertable/deleteuser', 'AdminController@deleteuser')    
->middleware('is_admin')    
->name('admin.deleteuser');
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
    var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token,
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }
    });
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if(confirm("Estas seguro de esto?"))
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('admin.deleteuser') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                id:id,
                _method: 'delete',
                _token: token
            },
            success:function(data) {
                //...
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey thank you, but the error is now "token is not defined"

Comment: You have to declare the variable and assign it the value before using it. Look at the updated answer where I put all toghether